# Is the UserHostAddress changed when using an F5 load balancer?

Tags: http

We are using a F5 load balancer for our servers.  Our VB code is checking the UserHostAddress using HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.  My question is, will this value return the IP from the load balancer, or does it still have the client IP address?

I will post this on ServerFault as well in case this is more of a server issue.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress will return load balancer ip address.

You can [configure](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2010/06/03/dire-load-balancing-straits-want-my-client-ip.aspx) F5 to include http header "X-Forwarded-For" that will contain client ip address.